# How do I make an HTML table have pagination without a bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I need to make my table have pagination. I am developing using React.js and using a simple `<table>` to display information that is being fetched.

The table uses mapping to dynamically grow when new information is generated through the UI. Currently, the table is just simply `<table>` tag that uses some CSS for styling. I would like to limit the number of rows to 10, and have pagination at the bottom for when there are more than 10 rows of data.

How can I achieve this?

```
<div className="app-container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Loan ID</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Amount (R)</th>
                <th>Rate (%)</th>
                <th>Term (Months)</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {Tokens.map((token) => (
                <tr>
                    <td>{token[0]}</td>
                    <td>{token[1]}</td>
                    <td>{token[2]}</td>
                    <td>{token[3]}</td>
                    <td>{token[4]}</td>
                    <td>{token[5]}</td>
                    <td>{token[6]}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean pure javascript or using other javascript libraries?

Comment: I would prefer to not have to import anything i havent written myself. Is there any built in parameters for pagination? In the way you can define the width of something like a div? Or is there no getting around the complex code that all of the google results show? I really just need to limit the number of rows to 10 and have a link at the bottom to the next page of rows. Nothing fancy or complicated, just to improve UX

Comment: It will definitely take you a decent amount of code to create a paging system. I know you said you wanted to use your own code, but that's what existing libraries are for (so you wont need to recreate the wheel). You could always just use jQuery DATATABLES its a very easy to use jQuery plugin. If your really against using jquery and that plugin im sure we can help you figure it out.

Comment: I saw lots of results talking about jquery but have no idea what it is. I have only really coded in c# the last 2 years, and some html. This project had me learn js and solidity but i am not proficient in either. I would love any help if it could be explained simply pls. I would use someone elses code if i was told how for sure

Comment: @ismaeeladams, if you don't want to spent time on writing your own pagination component, then you can use this npm package `react-paginate` => https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate